# TFS 2013 - Changeset counter increment for individual projects

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to migrate my existing code to TFS 2013 Express.
I have single Team Project Collection and inside it 3 team projects:

```
-web
-winforms
-wpf
```

If I add project `web-project1` (solution) to team project (for example to `web`) and check in I get info that change set **1** was saved.
If I add another project (`winforms-project1`) to other team project (`winforms`) and check in I get info that changeset **2** was saved.
If I return to first project (`web-project1`), change something and check in I get information that changeset **3** was saved, but this is my second commit to that project.

Can I configure TFS to have changeset incrementation counter for individual projects instead of one global counter for Team Project Collection?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, TFS changesets exist across the whole TeamCollection, so are shared amongst TeamProjects.

This allows you to copy and move projects with history and changeset info across TeamProject boundaries.

In your specific example, creating a Web & Winforms TeamProject sounds like you are going about it the wrong way and are starting off at too high a level.

Surely your UI projects could share Business Logic code? Therefore, they should belong in one TeamProject.

Comment: So my only option is to create 3 Team Project Collections?

Comment: @misiu: Why do you care about the changeset numbers?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I just wanted to know how many changes I made to specific project. i know i can see change history for item in web portal, but I wanted to have numbers one after the other. This is my first time with TFS, earlier I had separate SVN repos for projects, but now it is time to put everything together in one place

Comment: @Misiu: simple solution: use View History on the project, then select all and copy and, paste into Excel, then count the rows.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I discovered that couple of minutes ago :)